# Poisson effect formula for large deformations

Tags: statics, stress-strain

English Wikipedia in the [Poisson's ratio article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio#Width_change) gives an equation for large deformation:
$$
\frac{\Delta d}{d}=-1+\frac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{\Delta L}{L}\right)^\nu}
$$

I couldn't find any reference for this equation. Could someone help? I need it in my thesis, and I'd like to reference some other source than Wikipedia. Every other publication I've seen so far gives the approximate (linear) equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with differential form of Poisson's ratio:

$$\frac{\text{d} x}{x}=- \nu \frac{\text{d} l}{l}$$ 
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x} \frac{\text{d} x}{x}=- \nu \int_{l_0}^{l_0+\Delta l} \frac{\text{d} l}{l}$$
$$\ln \frac{x_0+\Delta x}{x_0}=- \nu \ln \frac{l_0+\Delta l}{l_0}$$
$$1 + \frac{\Delta x}{x_0}=\left(1+\dfrac{\Delta l}{l_0}\right)^{-\nu}$$